# Boxplot for two different data in one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataframe `df` which contains 2 columns: `A` , `B`.

I want to have one graph that contains `A` and `B` in the Y-axis. Note: I don't want to combine `A` and `B`. Each one of them has its own results.

So, the required output should contain for each single value of x-axis, two boxes ( one for `A` and one for `B`) beside each other(offset=0).

sample of `df`:

```
A      B

200.  30.        
100.  26.               
27.   25.       
25.   22.        
40.   21.       
20.   18.
```

I don't want to use reshape or inteaction. I'd rather use ggplot only with boxplot.

```
ReadData<-read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
A<-ggplot(ReadData,aes(A)+
   geom_boxplot(ReadData$A)

B<-ggplot(ReadData,aes(B)+ 
   geom_boxplot(ReadData$B)

print(A)
print(B)
```

It's not working? it complained about mapping aes !!! 
Any suugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text="A      B
200.  30.        
100.  26.               
27.   25.       
25.   22.        
40.   21.       
20.   18. ", header = TRUE)
```

The following code generates a barplot. It is not possible to generate a boxplot with one single value.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(stack(df), aes(x = rownames(df), y = values, fill = ind)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a single group?  There is but it is a bit of a hack,

Comment: There is a typo in the answer `rownames(stack(df))` not `rownames(df)`. Also, you can generate a boxplot if you change the value of `x` from `rownames` to `ind` (`aes(x = ind, y = values,fill=ind) + geom_boxplot()`)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer, and generating a boxplot

```
df <- read.table(text="A      B
200.  30.        
100.  26.               
27.   25.       
25.   22.        
40.   21.       
20.   18. ", header = TRUE)

ggplot(
    data = df %>% 
      pivot_longer( 
        cols = c(A, B),
        names_to = "x",
        values_to = "y",
      ),
    aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: Boxplot example]

You might want to tweak a bit this with respect to scales, add jittered points, etc.